# How to iterate over polygon points (in polygon_set_data) in Boost.polygon?

Tags: c++, boost, polygon, boost-polygon

How can I iterate over the points of a `polygon_set_data`?

It is possible to get the polygons in a `polygon_set_data` by using [`void get(output_container& output) const`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/polygon/doc/gtl_polygon_set_concept.htm), and then use the result to iterate over the points like in the below example, but this modifies the set and I would like to keep it untouched.

```
// [...] define polygons polySet & clip

polygon_set_data<int> result;
result.insert(polySet ^ clip); // some operations between polygons

std::vector<polygon_with_holes_data<int>> out;
result.get(out);
```

It is also possible to iterate over the edges of a `polygon_set_data` with its `begin()` method, but edges are not sorted.